# Fatal error: Call to undefined function text_view

Tags: call, php

I have a basic code here:

```
<?        
include("inc_dblib.php");
include("inc_ecs.php");
$db = dbconnect();
$id = 10;
?>
<?php echo text_view($db,$id,"<h3><br />^lead^</h1>   <br />^text^");?>
    <br />
```

inside inc_ecs.php i have:

```
function text_view($dblink,$id,$code) {

if( !$rset = dbquery($dblink,"article_view",$id) )
return FALSE;
$item = mysql_fetch_assoc($rset);
$text=$item["text"];
$title=$item["title"];
$lead=$item["lead"];
$capelo=$item["capelo"];
$author=$item["author"];

$vowels = array("^text^","^title^","^capelo^","^lead^", "^author^");                                                        
$yummy = array($text, $title, $capelo, $lead,$author);      
$code = str_replace($vowels,$yummy,$code);
return $code;
}
```

however every time I run my script it tells me

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function text_view

. Any ideas? Thanks.

Ok
so I found an other problem.
I have tried to insert the echo "Hello World!"; in the code of the inc_ecs.php.
When I browsed the page, I realised that a major part the code it is shown as text.
I turned back to the remote version and it shows a blank page when called in a browser.
the inc_ecs.php page start showning the code from "return $outputVar;" and the remaining hole code of the page is shown:

```
function graphical_counter ($db, $id){
    $str = counter($db, $id);
    $visitors_split = chunk_split ($str,1,'');
    $visitors = strlen($str);        
    for ($i ; $i< $visitors ; $i++){
        $outputVar .= "<img src='./images/counter/".$visitors_split[$i].".gif' width='15' height='20' border='0' align='absmiddle'>";
    }
    return $outputVar;
}
/*
End Counter Functions
```

Is there an error in this code ?

Comment: The function `textview()` as you posted it is invalid. Did you forget the closing bracket?

Comment: is this `include("inc_ecs.php");` displayed as it is on your window screen

Comment: Use <?php instead of <? because the short_tag sometimes is not "on" by default in the php.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your include(); should be inside of the  tag:

```
<?php
include("inc_ecs.php");
echo text_view($db,$id,"<h3><br />^lead^</h1>   <br />^text^");
?>
```

Comment: In your question you have the include outside the php code. If you copied it like that by mistake and you have it inside the <?php tag, check:
If the file name is correctly typed, and make sure both files are in the same directory, if not, specify the directory in the include: include("/directory/inc_ecs.php");

If that is still correct check that the function names coincide, and make sure it is declared within a <?php ?> tag as well.

Comment: I verified all this and it is fucntionning. My problem is that on a remote server, the page runs normally. But on a local server ... impossible to get it working

Comment: Are you sure you have both files? do a very simple test. On the inc_ecs.php add a echo "Hello World!" At beginning, so when you include it the page should show that. Do this to make sure the file is actually included. Because actually call to undefined function means that your main script can read your function text_view($dblink,$id,$code) { part

Comment: try of the hello world inserted on the top question.

Comment: And can you see the "hello world" on the main scrip echoed?

Comment: yes I do, I see the hole "echo "hello world!""
    End Counter Functions */ /* Basket functions */ echo "hello world!"; function ses_puttobasket($product_id, $quantity)//,

Comment: I mean, in your "basic script page" (I assume index.php) when you see it from the browser, if you see "Hello world" The echo "Hellow world" goes in your inc_ecs.php anyway, it's to check if the include() including the file actually.

Comment: oh, sorry! I got it now. in fact no, in my index.php I don't see this "hello world".
I'm trying to get www.mamias.org/index_backup.php working on local.

Comment: if you can't see the hello world it means that you are not really including inc_ecs.php then, make sure the name and directory are correct in the include, and are on the same server, you cannot include files on other servers. Also on your site I see that you have some really big pictures showing in a smaller size, the 3 big pictures at bottom, that is wrong as you are wasting bandwith and increasing loading time, resize those pictures :P, also the text on your footer are in the image, so google won't get that text.

Comment: ok, 
Under the same httpdocs folder i have among others (I copied names directely form the folder):
index_backup.php
inc_ecs.php
inc_dblib.php
The index_backup.php bigins with:
    <?        
 include("inc_dblib.php");
 include("inc_ecs.php");
 $db = dbconnect();
    $id = 10;
    ?>
Is the fact that the code is showing when opening inc_ecs.php on a navigator, abnormal, or not ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a way to send you the two files: index_backup.php and inc_ecs.php ?

Comment: I fixed it, Just replace your <? tag with <?php both in the index.php and inc_ecs.php. (and everywhere else). Avoid using "<?"(short tag) Because on some php installations the option in the php.ini (short_tag) is "Off" by default, and can cause this kind of problems if you are not aware/careful. Replace everywhere your <? tags with <?php and it's fixed, just tried it.

Comment: i did it, but nothing changes locally.
I'am still also find other kind of error:
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_pconnect() in C:\wamp\www\xxx\httpdocs\db_conn.php on line 4
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0009 699464 {main}( ) ..\countrystatistics.php:0
2 0.0015 702840 include( 'C:\wamp\www\xxx\httpdocs\db_conn.php' ) ..\countrystatistics.php:2

the db_connect has:
   <?php
   $conn = pg_pconnect("host=localhost dbname=xxx user=xxx password=xxx")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
   ?>

Comment: ho laa, is it my postgresql server witch is not functionning ?
how to test it ?